# Body will not align on different resolution

Tags: html, css, resolution

Everything is working fine on my default resolution; however, when I run my website on another resolution everything goes to the right instead of center. Why is this? I have tried setting the overflow to 0%.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>   
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
        <h2 id="bannertext"> Websites4u </h2>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonbar">
            <a id="homeb" href="webpageone.html">Home</a>
            <a id="aboutb" href="fake.html">About</a>
            <a id="contactb" href="webpage2.html">Contact Us!</a>

        </div>

        <div id="mainbody">

        <p id="radio">
        3gb:   <input type="radio" name="age" value ="<3gb"> <br> <br>
        4gb:   <input type="radio" name="age" value ="4gb"> <br> <br>
        8gb:   <input type="radio" name="age" value ="8gb"> <br> <br>
        16gb: <input type="radio" name="age" value ="16gb"> <br>
        </p>

        <h4 id="bodytext"> Please Select Your Hardware </h4>

        <h3 id="Ram"> Ram </h3>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    h1 {
        color:blue;
    }
    body{
        width:1280px;
        height:720px;
        background-image:url("background colour.jpg");
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #banner{
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 148%;
        border: medium solid BFBDBA;
        background-color:F1C43E;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #bannertext{
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #buttonbar {
        position: relative;
        height: 30px;
        width: 148% ;
        border: medium solid BFBDBA;
        background-color:lightgrey;
        color:white;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
        font-style:bold;
    }
    #homeb {
        position: relative;
        left: 450px;
    }

    #aboutb{
        position: relative;
        left: 500px;
    }

    #contactb{
        position: relative;
        left: 550px;
    }

    a { 
        color: white; 
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        COLOR: orange;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    #bodytext{
        position: relative;
        top:50px;
        left:50px;
        color:red;
        font-size:35px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
    }

    #mainbody{
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 80%;
        left: 30%;
        top: 5px;
        border:medium solid F1C43E;
    }

    #radio{
        position: absolute;
        top: 240px;
        left:100px;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #Ram{
        position: absolute;
        top: 176px;
        left: 100px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: Green;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to fix all your issues quickly. Your basic mistake is that you have absolute values for every item.

For instance:

```
 body{
    width:1280px;
    height:720px;
    background-image:url("background colour.jpg");
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Because of width specified there, your content will always have width of 1280px when you open it on a screen with smaller width it will be still rendered with width of 1280px and because of overflow:hidden you will see it simply like it is shifted to the right side. When you do something with computer it will do not what you WANT, but what you ask it to do. And overflow:hidden simply hide everything outside of visible area, not center content like you want.

For #buttonbar:

```
 #buttonbar {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 148% ;
    border: medium solid BFBDBA;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    color:white;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
    font-style:bold;
    }
```

- even have no idea why do you need `width:148%` here. Buttons inside it are centered with absolute positions:

```
#homeb {
    position: relative;
    left: 450px;    
}
```

left:450px strictly says to browser: hey, put this #homeb on the 450th px inside its parent block. And browser will do it like that and will not shift it to little more left because you want it to be centered.
You may tell him to place all buttons in center:

```
  #buttonbar {
        height: 30px;
        text-align:center;
        border: medium solid BFBDBA;
        background-color:lightgrey;
        color:white;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
        font-style:bold;
    }
```

text-align:center; - this will tell browser to center content inside of #buttonbar not depending on its width, and no need to define classes for #homeb, #aboutb and #contactb.

And so on. There are to many places to fix. I gave you a starting point. Here is demo with some changes already done for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2rM6K/7/

You just need to understand what each line of your code means for browser if you want to get something working correctly. If you do not understand how something works - there is a lot of info in web and people are ready to help you. Just do not expect that some magic happens while you writing a code - you must learn how things work. Read, try, experiment, read again, try again, experiment again until you start understanding why and how something works.

Answer (score 0):

```
page
{
Margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
}
```

u can change width according to your requirement.